# Implement a while loop in my hangman type/puzzle game

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, pygame

I'm new to python programming. I would like to display a win message after every correct letter input and no message if an incorrect letter is input.

I've written my code such that it will only accept one letter at a time and reduce an attempt by 1, regardless of if it is wrong or right.

How would I be able to implement a while loop into this so that I don't keep getting this error:

> builtins.TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

```
word="banana"
word_list=list(word)
length=len(word_list)
word_list= set(word_list)
word_list=list(word_list)
answer=["_"]*length
answer=list(answer)
guess=[]
count = 4
    win=False # boolean so we do not use an identifier in our if statements     
    user_guess=window.input_string("Guess a letter: ", x, y)
    y = y + font_height
    guess.append(user_guess)
    while count > 0:
        # Removes guesses if they are not in the word so that the blanks do not fill in with incorrect letters
        for letter in guess:
            if  letter not in word_list:
                guess.remove(letter)
            else:
                win=True
        # Replaces blanks in empty list with the letter guess
        for place,letter in enumerate(list(word)):
            for i in range(len(guess)):
                if letter == guess[i]:
                    answer[place]=guess[i] 
        answer=" ".join(answer)
        update_message = 'The answer so far is: '
        window.draw_string(update_message + answer,x,y)
        y = y + font_height
    #End Game
    win_message = 'Good job! You got the word.'
    lose_message = 'Not quite, the correct word was: '+word +' Better luck next time'

    if win:
        window.draw_string(win_message,x,y)
        y = y + font_height
        count -=1
    else:
        window.draw_string(lose_message,x,y)
        y = y + font_height
        count -=1
```

Comment: What library do you use? Doesn't look like pygame. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Please notice this assignment: `answer=" ".join(answer)`. Before the assignment, `answer` is a list of string. After the assignment, `answer` becomes a string.

So, in the next iteration of the `while` loop, `answer[place]=guess[i]` turns invalid, because python does not allow modifying a string by assigning a "character" to some place of the string.

It really takes some time to find the fault. You'd better provide the information, like, "which line in the program targeted the error message", when asking questions in future.